# Kotlin button causing crash when trying to switch activity?

Tags: xml, kotlin, button, android-activity

I am trying to use a button to go to from a sign in page to a register page but for some reason it isn't working. From my understanding this process should be relatively simple but for some reason the action doesn't function as hoped.

I've tried using intent as I have for other pages but it just crashes the app (see Example 1). I do have another function on the same page using intent, is this an issue.

Example 1

```
        val goToRegisterButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.goToRegisterButton)
        goToRegisterButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val regIntent = Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(regIntent)
        }
```

I then tried calling a function which would do thintent side of things but again no luck (See Example 2).

Example 2

```
        val goToRegisterButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.goToRegisterButton)
        goToRegisterButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            goRegisterActivity()
            
        }
```

```
    private fun goRegisterActivity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "goRegisterActivity")
        val regIntent = Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(regIntent)
    }
```

Edit: I was asked to add the stack trace, I think this is it.
[stack trace of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygr4u.png)

Comment: Just to be clear: do you see a crash or nothing happens? If the answer is crash, can you, please, attach a stack trace?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin , it was a crash and I've added what I think is the stack trace

Comment: Have you called `setContentView` in your Activity? The crash says that the view is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's actually crashing? The Activity containing the button, or `RegisterActivity` after you click the button? Your error (please post the stacktrace as text in a code block next time! No text as images) says an Activity is failing to start because of an attempt to call `findViewById` before a `Window`, and that implies you're doing it at construction time, in a top-level variable like this:

```
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val badIdea = findViewById<Whatever>(R.id.some_id)
}
```

You can't do that because you don't have a view hierarchy until `setContentView` is called (so there's no view to find), and at construction time you don't have a `Context` to even call it on, which is why you're getting a crash. View lookups have to be done in `onCreate` or later, when your `Activity` is associated with a `Context`